# Hashtable serial

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am using Following code to get the account balance for getting balance statement in my Software.

Here are details :

**ASP** is class name
**Rev_AllAccountBalaces** is a function which returns datatable;
**BalanceSheetEndDate** is DateTime Object
**ano1** is Column name of returned datatable
**account_balance** Is a hash table

**Code :**

```
DataTable dt_all_account_balances = ASP.Rev_AllAccountBalaces(BalanceSheetEndDate);

for (int idx = 0; idx < dt_all_account_balances.Rows.Count; idx++)

{                        
  int ano = Int32.Parse(dt_all_account_balances.Rows[idx]["ano1"].ToString());
  double balance = double.Parse(dt_all_account_balances.Rows[idx]["balance1"].ToString());
  account_balance.Add(ano, balance);                   
}
```

Now let's come to the problem..

While adding values and keys to the "account_balance" , the values are added in Order of adding..

e.g.
Suppose
keys    values
96  40000
1091    5906
1088    99
1087    4939
1089    49
99  -40000
415 -53993
1036    -100000
1090    1000
1076    42000

they are actually added as
1088    99
1076    42000
1036    -100000
1091    5906
1090    1000
1089    49
99  -40000
1087    4939
96  40000
415 -53993

Why???????

How to add them as like as Datatable values...???

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable is a map and it is not ordered. Try to use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).